# Infinety Filemanager 2.1 - Laravel Nova 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

This Error :

`Class Infinety\Filemanager\FilemanagerTool`
contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Laravel\Nova\Tool::menu)

This code of `NovaServiceProvider`

```
public function tools()
    {
        return [
            new \Infinety\Filemanager\FilemanagerTool(),
        ];
    }
```

This Docs link Nova-Filemanager
https://infinetyes.github.io/Nova-Filemanager/2.1/installation.html

Comment: I'm guessing the version you're using is not 2.1.